# Laravel Keeps Flattening My Input Array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to make a dynamic editing form for multiple items at a time in Laravel. For this, I'm using an Input naming convention of:

```
name="groups[][name]"
```

...

```
name="groups[][description]"
```

For whatever reason, trying to process this form in Laravel always results in the 'groups' input being a flat array. I fetch the set with:

```
$request->input('groups');

and var_dump shows:

    array(
    10
)
    {
    [0] => array(
        1
    )
        {
        ["name"] => string(15) "Baseball Cardsf"
        }

    [1] => array(
        1
    )
        {
        ["description"] => string(22) "Baseball Cards Section"
        }

    [2] => array(
        1
    )
        {
        ["id"] => string(1) "6"
        }

    [3] => array(
        1
    )
        {
        ["willDelete"] => string(5) "false"
        }

    [4] => array(
        1
    )
        {
        ["hasUpdated"] => string(4) "true"
        }

    [5] => array(
        1
    )
        {
        ["name"] => string(12) "Board Gamesf"
        }

    [6] => array(
        1
    )
        {
        ["description"] => string(19) "Board Games Section"
        }

    [7] => array(
        1
    )
        {
        ["id"] => string(1) "5"
        }

    [8] => array(
        1
    )
        {
        ["willDelete"] => string(5) "false"
        }

    [9] => array(
        1
    )
        {
        ["hasUpdated"] => string(4) "true"
        }
    }
```

Is this a mistake in my formatting, or is this an issue specific to Laravel?

**Update**

The issue was formatting. Using $loop->index to fill the empty []'s fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you have mistake in formatting, everytime you name your inputs `groups[]` the input index is incremented by 1, you must name your inputs like this:

```
1st item
name="groups[0][name]"
name="groups[0][description]"

2nd item
name="groups[1][name]"
name="groups[1][description]"
```

You can add an iterator or something.

Comment: I tried doing this using $loop->index, and it worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may take a temporary array and set each key like `name`, `description` etc. into it and finally assign it to groups.

e.g.

```
foreach ($items as $key=>$item){
  $t = array(); 
  $t["name"] = $item["name"]; 
  $t["description"]=  $item["description"];
  $groups[] = $t; 
}
```